# Обтекание TextView вокруг ImageView

Tags: android, java

Всем привет! Имеется ImageView и справа от него TextView. TextVeiw разной длинны, поэтому хотелось бы чтобы этот TextView обтекал изображение. Примерно вот так: http://html.net/tutorials/css/figure016.gif Возможно это сделать?

Comment: не думаю, что такое возможно стандартными средствами, но присоединяюсь к вопросу.    
Как вариант - добавить 2 текствью(справа и снизу изображения), и переносить во второй текст, который не влазит в первый...

Comment: [Читайте](http://gmariotti.blogspot.de/2014/03/snippet-align-textview-around-image.html) , делайте.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/